# Using plural names for variable lists (General Programming Style)

Tags: python, coding-style

Due to programming extensively with Lists in Python, I have been naming many list variables, and iterative variables for iterating in the lists. Is it readable in general specific to Python) to use plurals for lists and singular forms for the iterative variable? Furthermore, do different coding conventions have different answers?

For instance:

```
room_states = []  
for room_state in room_states:  
    ...
```

I find it easier to understand, but it may give some trouble to other programmers who attempt to read my program, confusing one with the other.

Comment: You can use singular + plural the way you do. It is not ambiguous, and if people mix up plurals with singulars they have other issues. I myself think it's good practice.

Comment: There are many examples all over the stdlib documentation and source of exactly this (`for iterable in iterables:`, `for value in values:`) or similar style (`for it in iterables:`, `for key in uniquekeys:`). I might avoid it in cases where an irregular plural might be unfamiliar or odd to some readers (`radius in radii`, `datum in data`, `penny in pence`, `stratum in strata`, etc.), but otherwise, there's nothing to worry about.